# nginx location wildcard or inheritance for directories

Tags: nginx

```
location /slides/*/ {
  autoindex on;
  charset utf-8;
}
```

does not work.  how would I open all subdirectories under /slides/ to allow autoindex?

Comment: Have you tried `location ~ /slides/*/` or `location = /slides/*/`?

Comment: Or `location ~ /slides/*/*`, `location = /slides/*/*` (adding `*` at the end of the path)

Comment: `location ~ /slides/*/` does the job.  can you add this as an answer for me to accept, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the `~` for regex patterns:

```
location ~ /slides/*/ {
  autoindex on;
  charset utf-8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no location wildcard in Nginx and it is not necessary.

`location /slides/` matches URLs which **begin with** `/slides/` and this includes all paths and directories below it **unless** another `location` takes precedence.

See [how Nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration) and [the location directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

Comment: maybe this is how it should be, but I don't think this was the case here.  I only had `autoindex on`, never turned off anywhere else.  but `location ~ /slides/*/` worked.